# Jetpack compose navigation with viewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I'm trying to use Jetpack Compose navigation inside `viewModel`. when navigation gets triggered nothing happens. here's my approach:

I define `NavigationDestination`. In my case, I have four screen: welcome, sign in, sign up,
and survey

```
interface NavigationDestination {
    val route: String
}

sealed class Screen(override val route: String) : NavigationDestination {

    object WelcomeScreen : Screen("welcome")
    object SignInScreen : Screen("signIn")
    object SignUpScreen : Screen("signUp")
    object SurveyScreen : Screen("survey")

}
```

the `Navigator`, which exposes the current destination with the default screen of `WelcomeScreen`.

```
class Navigator {

    var destination: MutableStateFlow<NavigationDestination> = MutableStateFlow(Screen.WelcomeScreen)

    fun navigate(destination: NavigationDestination) {
        this.destination.value = destination
    }

}
```

In the main composable, I obtain the `NavHostController` and listen for changes to the `Navigator`.

```
@Composable
fun JetSurvey0App() {
    val welcomeViewModel: WelcomeViewModel = viewModel(factory = WelcomeViewModelFactory())
    val navigator = Navigator()
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val destination by navigator.destination.collectAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(destination) {
        if (navController.currentDestination?.route != destination.route) {
            navController.navigate(destination.route)
        }
    }

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = navigator.destination.value.route) {
        composable(Screen.WelcomeScreen.route) {
            WelcomeScreen(
                onEvent = { event ->
                    when (event) {
                        is WelcomeEvent.SignInSignUp -> welcomeViewModel.handleContinue(event.email)
                        WelcomeEvent.SignInAsGuest -> welcomeViewModel.signInAsGuest()
                    }
                }
            )
        }
        composable(Screen.SignUpScreen.route) {
            SignUp()
        }
        composable(Screen.SignInScreen.route) {
            SignIn()
        }
        composable(Screen.SurveyScreen.route) {
            SurveyQuestionsScreen()
        }


    }
}
```

here in `WelcomeViewModel` I perform decoupled navigation by invoking the `Navigator` like so.

```
class WelcomeViewModel(
    private val userRepository: UserRepository,
    private val navigator: Navigator
    ) : ViewModel() {

    fun handleContinue(email: String) {
        if (userRepository.isKnownUserEmail(email)) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
              navigator.navigate(Screen.SignInScreen)
            }
        } else {
          viewModelScope.launch {
              navigator.navigate(Screen.SignUpScreen)
          }
        }
    }

    fun signInAsGuest() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            navigator.navigate(Screen.SurveyScreen)
        }
        userRepository.signInAsGuest()
    }


}

class WelcomeViewModelFactory : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(WelcomeViewModel::class.java)) {
            return WelcomeViewModel(UserRepository, Navigator()) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`collectAsState` triggers recomposition each time you emit a new value to the flow. It means, that `JetSurvey0App` will be re-called.

You're trying to navigate using `navigator.destination`, but you're creating a new object on each recomposition:

```
val navigator = Navigator()
val destination by navigator.destination.collectAsState()
```

You can make your `WelcomeViewModel.navigator` `public` instead of `private` and collect its `destination` - as you change the state of this particular object.

Read more about recompositions in [Compose Mental Model](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#recomposition).

Comment: to do this I need 3 checkmark.  could give me one. and later I'll do it